# install plotly for R on Debian 9.7

Tags: r, debian, r-plotly

I am struggling to install `Plolty` on a **Debian 9.7 VM** and **R**. I keep getting this error

```
Loading required package: shiny
Error in library(plotly) : there is no package called ‘plotly’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
Execution halted
```

The following are all the packages that I am installing on Debian:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    xtail \
    wget \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
```

I have also tried to replace `libcurl4-openssl-dev` with `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` but I keep getting the same error!

Any Idea?

Comment: what did you run exactly to install plotly? And where?

Comment: to install plolty and other R packages I have used the following command. 
`RUN R -e "install.packages(c('memoise','plotly','DBI','RSQLite','RPostgreSQL' repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"`

Comment: when you run this command, do you get warning or error messages?

Comment: dear @MLavoie ,I have gone through all the output and sometimes there is the following message `virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory`. I have checked my memory using `free -m` and 70% of it is free so I don't understand the problem

Comment: It's hard to help without all the information. You should include in your post the code you ran to install plotly. You could also add the R version as well. Did you install other packages?